# Can have A column Like this when creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-view

```
CREATE VIEW sales_summary_v AS
COLUMN Max HEADING Max FORMAT $99,999.99;
COLUMN Min HEADING Min FORMAT $99,999.99;
SELECT MAX(Value) as Max, MIN(value) as Min
FROM Table_name;
```

Comment: Huh?  I assume this is Oracle?  You are intermixing sqlplus statements with SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Number Format Model***](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) with a leading dollar sign(*`FM$99,999.99`*) may be used as in the following :

```
CREATE VIEW sales_summary_v AS
SELECT to_char(MAX(Value),'FM$99,999.99') as Max, 
       to_char(MIN(Value),'FM$99,999.99') as Min
  FROM Table_name;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37743/1)